# How to stop auto indexing of _id using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose

I have the following schema definition:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var EmpSchema = new Schema({
    EmpName: {type: String},
    EmpRefered : {type: [String]},
});
```

So, now `_id` is auto generated and is automatically indexed. For a specific reasons on some of the schema I don't want index on even `_id` field.

To do this I have tried the following code:

```
options = {config:{autoIndex:false}};
var db2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/DBName', options);
```

As per the [API docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-createConnection) it should be work. Could anyone put some light if I am missing anything or any other way to do the same.

Note: But I would not prefer to pull native driver and command to drop all indexes.

Comment: [You cannot remove the _id index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/indexes/#default-id-index)

Comment: @joao, indeed you can disable index on `_id` field. see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/

Comment: @Saleem the autoIndexId ia deprecated and will be removed in version 3.4 according to the doc page you just linked.

Comment: @joao yes you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if you can disable auto index on `_id` in mongoose, but you can indeed disable it from `mongo shell`. However, keep in mind that this setting is applied on collection level.

You'll be creating collection with custom options.

```
db.createCollection('collection', {autoIndexId: false})
```

However, keep in mind that if you disable auto indexing on `_id`, replication will not work.

Please see [db.createCollection()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/)